# Thermal photon mass

Tags: photons, mass, effective-field-theory, thermal-field-theory

I am currently researching the generation of thermal mass in photons within the framework of quantum field theory at finite temperature. In such as formalism, one can define longitudinal and perpendicular masses, denoted by $m_L$ and $m_T$ respectively, with these masses being proportional to the projectors $P_L^{\mu\nu}$ and $P_T^{\mu\nu}$. My question pertains to determining the total photon thermal mass. Is it accurately represented as $m_\text{total}^2 = m_L^2 + m_T^2$, or is it given by $m_\text{total} = m_L + m_T$, or perhaps another combination altogether?

I appreciate your assistance in clarifying this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: You may need to provide more context. In what theory does this thermal mass appear?

Comment: @flippiefanus in a QEd plasma à-la Lebellac.